# Entityframework Core Ingenieria Inversa borra los Dataanotations

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework-core, dataannotations

Estoy aprendiendo **ASP.NET Core Razor Page** y cuando vínculo mi Base de Datos **MySQL** con **EF Core**, aplicando **Reverse Engineer** debido a que la BD existe, hasta aquí todo muy bien. El problema se presenta cuando le coloco los **DataAnnotations** para validar las propiedades y aplicar reglas, si actualizo el modelo todo el DataAnnotations se **borra**. He visto bastantes Post pero no me queda muy claro como solucionar este problema. Si alguien me hecha una mano explicandome como resolvería esto estaré eternamente agradecido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias decirnos que fue lo que ya probaste o viste, para no señalarte exactamente lo mismo?

Answer (score 1):

Personalmente no recomendaria usar `DataAnnotation` me incluno mas por la notacion `fluent`, asi separas la definicion de la entidad del mapping

Pero podria sugerir que los cambios particulares que apliques los realices en un `partial class` asi al actualizar no afectara lo que definas en ese otra clases que estara en un .cs separado

[Clases y métodos parciales (Guía de programación de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods)

Entonces defines en un .cs por ejemplo

```
public partial class Entidad1 {

  //propiedades Reverse Engineer

}
```

y en otro .cs defines

```
public partial class Entidad1 {

  //propiedades propias

}
```

entonces al actualizar el .cs que defienes separado no se vera afectado por lo cambios

Recuerda si que deben estar bajo el mismo namespace

Comment: Tengo otra dudas, en Entityframework core todas las entidades se copian dentro de una carpeta contendora la cual pasa a ser parte del Namespace, si hago otra carpeta para contener las entidades creadas por mi con los dataannotations estas luego como se vinculan al contexto generado por el reverse engineer

Comment: Las partial class se unen solas, solo que si creas una carpeta diferente puede que tome esta como nombre del namespace de las clases que pongas alli dentro, pero puedes cambiarlo y usar el mismo que aplica EF

Comment: Antes que nada Leandro, gracias por tus respuesta. No he podido resolver el problema. No permite que se haga otra clase con el mismo nombre bajo el mismo Namespace. Trate de usar fluent como mencionas pero viene mas optimizado para usar con MVC y ahora mismo estoy usando MVVM Page Model con Razor y al parecer no funciona igual que los ejemplos que tiene la página y la documentación. Tendre que enfocarme en la validación del lado cliente con JQuery o algo asi...